# How to save output of python-swiftclient to file when dowloading a directory?

Tags: command-line, io, command-line-tool, file-io

When I download files from a cloud with [python-swiftclient](https://www.swiftstack.com/docs/integration/python-swiftclient.html) sometimes I get errors like this one:

> Error downloading object 'uploads/1/image.png': Object GET failed: https://orbit.brightbox.com/v1/acc-12345/uploads/1/image.png 500 Internal Error   b'An error occurred'

To search for the all errors and re-download failed files I would want to save output of the `swift` command to a file

I tried to do the following ways:

```
swift-cli -A https://orbit.brightbox.com/v1/acc-12345 \
  -U user -K secret download uploads 2>&1 | tee uploads.log

# and

swift-cli -A https://orbit.brightbox.com/v1/acc-12345 \
  -U user -K secret download uploads > uploads.log
```

But this didn't work. `man swift` describes -o option

> For a single object download, you may use the -o [--output]  
>   option to redirect the output to a specific file or if "-" then just redirect to stdout or with --no-download actually not to write anything  to  disk.

but when I try to download a directory with `-o` option if fails with

```
-o option only allowed for single file downloads
```

How can I save log to a file when I download a directory with swift CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Actually redirecting output to a file works with `swift-client`:

```
swift-cli -A https://orbit.brightbox.com/v1/acc-12345 \
  -U user -K secret download uploads > uploads.log
```

I was confused because after I started the command above, in another terminal window I did

```
tail -f uploads.log
```

But it didn't give me any output (like I was seeing when I was running the download command without redirection).

Seems like that `swift-client` writes to a file in batches and I needed to wait about a minute until `tail -f` dumps into the console a hundred of lines like this

```
uploads/documents/1/image.png [auth 0.000s, headers 0.390s, total 14.361s, 0.034 MB/s]
```